# Swift: get value using async method

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

I'm looking for a good idiom or two for this situation:

I want to convert a CLLocationCoordinate2D to a CLPlacemark with an asynchronous reverse geolocation call, as part of a sequence of other operations.

The conversion step is very much a "utility" step, so putting a lot of code in the handler to do the "other operations" feels like poor structure.

I can store the result in a class variable but then I need to know when the async step has completed, which means some kind of event trigger or queueing of the main thread with timeouts or something, which also seem awkward.

Is there a standard approach to this? Is it common to just put the code in the handler?

Thanks!

Here's the specific code for my context, FWIW.

```
func getPlaceFromCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLPlacemark? {

    var loc = CLLocation(
        latitude: coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: coordinate.longitude
    )

    var mightBeAPlace: CLPlacemark? = nil

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            println("Reverse geocoding error.")
        }
        else if (placemarks.count == 0) {
            println("no placemarks")
        }
        else { // if (placemarks.count > 0)
            println("we have placemarks")
            mightBeAPlace = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark)
            println("Inside closure place: \(mightBeAPlace?.locality)")
            lastUserSelectedPlace = mightBeAPlace // This stores it in a class variable.
        }
    })
    println("Outside closure place: \(mightBeAPlace?.locality)")
    return mightBeAPlace // This of course fails because the async task is running separately.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical approach is to adopt the `completionHandler` approach yourself, e.g.:

```
lazy var geocoder = CLGeocoder()

func getPlaceFromCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completionHandler: (CLPlacemark!, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        if error != nil {
            println("Reverse geocoding error: \(error)")
        } else if placemarks.count == 0 {
            println("no placemarks")
        }

        completionHandler(placemarks.first as? CLPlacemark, error)
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
getPlaceFromCoordinate(coordinate) { placemark, error in 
    if placemark != nil {
        // use placemark here
    }
}

// but do not use it here, because the above runs asynchronously (i.e. later)
```

In terms of how much code you put in this `completionHandler` closure, and how much you put in `getPlaceFromCoordinate`, that's entirely a function of what that code entails. But as much routine code that is repeated (e.g. logging of errors, what have you) inside the `getPlaceFromCoordinate`, and hopefully the closure will be limited to taking the `CLPlacemark` and updating model objects and/or UI.

But, yes, the convention is to put anything contingent upon the completion of the asynchronous method inside the completion handler. While there are techniques to make this asynchronous method behave synchronously, that's generally a very bad idea.

If you're finding that the code inside the closure is getting unwieldy, then engage in functional decomposition and move this code into its own function and have the completion handler simply call that. Or there are other asynchronous patterns, too (e.g. asynchronous `NSOperation` subclasses with dependencies between them, promises/futures, etc.). But use an asynchronous pattern.

Comment: Thanks @rob. What still nags at me are a couple of issues I can anticipate.

* If the async bit were used in many places, I'd have some duplicate code where in a synchronous setting I'd tend to use a utility function or something. See my answer below for my solution to this.

*  If I had several asynchronous operations to do, it seems like I'd end up with a nested chain of async calls which is both convoluted and inefficient. I'm sure this is a standard idiom and how to wait on multiple async steps to complete deserves its own question.

Comment: I'm unclear as to how your answer differs from mine (other than making the closure optional), but I guess if you're happy, I am, too.

Comment: Upon a closer look, it's the same :) That's what I get for reading it last night while my four year old sat on my lap watching Zig and Sharko! :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach I decided on is to write the getPlaceFromCoordinate function to accept an optional closure, so the calling method can control what's done with the result of the lookup.

```
func getPlaceFromCoordinate(
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
        placeAction: ((CLPlacemark) -> Void)?
    ) {

        :
    // Reverse geocode.
        :

    //  If we get a good placemark:
    if (placeAction != nil) {
        placeAction!(placemark)
    }

    }
```

This seems suitably straightforward for the context, flexible and puts the calling code back "in the drivers seat". Not sure what other pros or cons there might be.

Comment: BTW, an easier approach to optional closures is replace that `if placeAction != nil` and forced unwrapping with a simple optional invocation of the closure (e.g. `placeAction?(placemark)`).

Comment: Nice idiom to learn, that. :) My naïve reading of that would have been that it would fail if placeAction were nil, so it's a nice one to learn!